# Composite Unique Update Violation In Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a table with a composite unique, I would to allow users to swap sequence numbers but SQL throws a unique key violation. Presumably because the violations are checked after each row change

```
public class RateCodes
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   //Unique Composite Key Field 1
   public int Sequence { get; set; }
   //Unique Composite Key Field 2
   public int DivisionId { get; set; }
   public Decimal RateCode { get; set; }
}
```

In our client we want to allow a user reorder the sequence of their rate codes.

However when I perform an update I get an exception

> "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UX_RateCodes_Sequence'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.RateCodes'. The duplicate key value is (346, 3)

Despite the fact that I'm saving all at once, SQL is throwing a unique violation because SQL performs the unique key validation before all of the data is updated.

I don't want to delete my data before saving because other application could be operating on the table and I might not have all of the data in the current application. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: why not update the existing records instead of inserting new ones and then deleting the old ones?

Comment: @Marathon55 I am Updating the Existing records, They're throwing a unique voilation because SQL performs Unique Key Validation before all of the Data is updated, Despite saving it all at once

Comment: Are you using the `UpdateRange` method? If so, maybe you can loop through and update them one at a time instead.

Comment: @Marathon55 Looping through them would cause the same issue

Comment: So you have an existing record with Id=346 and Sequence=3. You want to change the RateCode value of that record, right?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I Solve this issue?

This is not a terribly easy problem to solve, as stated.  Updating keys is inherently problematic, and unique constraints are not deferrable.

An easy way to solve this with modeling is to introduce a new, non-key attribute to store the ordering.  This has the added benefit of allowing you to use a decimal or float for the ordering column, so you an always insert in item between two existing items.

Another idea is to use the new attribute to store the to-be ordering, after a series of updates and delete, issue a single

```
update RateCodes set sequence = sequence_new 
where id = @id and sequence_new is not null
```

to perform the recording in a single statement.  You could do the same pattern with a temp table that re-maps the values.  But all of this requires some level of direct SQL coding.

Comment: Thanks, Plus one for the Idea, but how can I have a unique Non Key attribute, partitioned by another field?

Comment: It wouldn't be unique.  Allowing duplicates makes updates simple.  And you can use the key values to break ties if you need to impose a complete, stable ordering on retrieval.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense, you may have a stable sort but it doesn’t make it the correct one. Say an update anomaly occurs putting in duplicate sequence numbers, so you sort then by the key, but that assumes that the insertion order is correct when it might not be. Now instead of throwing an error, you pay the person the wrong rate

Comment: How an anomaly can occure if you are in control and your code is transactional?

Comment: @Aldert 2 people concurrently update the same resource

Comment: @johnny5 *2 people concurrently update the same resource* [cannot happen with entity-framework, all updates are wrapped in a transaction](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/transaction-in-entity-framework.aspx).

Comment: @ErikPhilips I mean concurrently from a clients perspective,  2 users access the same resource at the same time, 1 updates the resource to add a new order,  The other does the same thing.  With this answer nothing stops the DB for having incorrect data.  Even Validations at the Business Layer, other applications have access to the DB.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Also, where does that resource specify you can't update the same enitity concurrently?  Are you saying its impossible for both transaction to succeed?   I thought you have to opt into concurrency tokens, According to this you have to [Enabled Detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#concurrency-conflicts)